# WPF - Binding the Headers of TabItems

Tags: wpf, width, center, tabitem

In WPF, I'm trying to bind the Headers of my TabItems to a property of their respective ViewModels/Presenters (which are logical children of their respective TabItems). 
This property (Name) is of type String. This is within a ContentPresenter, which in turn is part of a ControlTemplate, which otherwise works fine.

My question: IF WE ASSUME that the DataContext and the Path are set correctly, which should be the case, is there any reason why this code shouldn't work as intended?

This is the code:

```
<ContentPresenter 
     HorizontalAlignment="Center"
     ContentSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource    
     AncestorType=TabItem}, Path=Content.DataContext.CurrentlyEditedBand.Name}"
     Height="21" />
```

Edit to Add: Instead of ContentSource I've also tried setting the Header property of TabItem, but then the compiler complains  that Header is not recognized or not accessible.

Comment: Well, it looks like it will work when I replace ContentSource by Content. Will do the definitive test later.

Comment: Try this: Path=DataContext.CurrentlyEditedBand.Name or Path=CurrentlyEditedBand.Name Basically when u templated each tabitem gets the data context as current item so technically second suggestion should do for u